# Add picture link in "About Me" page

Tags: support, profile-page, hyperlinks

I want to provide a link to my LinkedIn profile on the About Me page of my StackOverflow profile in the form of a link badge. LinkedIn offers several link badges and their HTML code.

I chose one badge and its HTML code is:

```
<a href="http://pk.linkedin.com/pub/ghazanfar-abbas/27/a/18b">

<img src="http://www.linkedin.com/img/webpromo/btn_viewmy_160x33.png" width="160" height="33" border="0" alt="View Ghazanfar Abbas's profile on LinkedIn">

</a>
```

In the LinkedIn instructions, it is written that just copy and paste the code where I want to show the badge.
How can I use the above code to display the badge with my LinkedIn profile link on the About Me page of my profile?
I have no idea how to write or use HTML.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can translate that to Markdown quite easily:

```
[![View Ghazanfar Abbas's profile on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/img/webpromo/btn_viewmy_160x33.png)](http://pk.linkedin.com/pub/ghazanfar-abbas/27/a/18b)
```

which becomes:

[image: View Ghazanfar Abbas's profile on LinkedIn]

That's a `![alt text](url)` image link nested inside of a `[link item](url)` markdown link. You could use `[...][#]` numbered links too:

```
[![View Ghazanfar Abbas's profile on LinkedIn][1]][2]

[1]: https://www.linkedin.com/img/webpromo/btn_viewmy_160x33.png
[2]: http://pk.linkedin.com/pub/ghazanfar-abbas/27/a/18b
```

Alternatively, you can re-use the HTML LinkedIn provides, but you'll have to stick to the [HTML subset supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites).

The following HTML works:

```
<a href="http://pk.linkedin.com/pub/ghazanfar-abbas/27/a/18b">

<img src="https://www.linkedin.com/img/webpromo/btn_viewmy_160x33.png" width="160" height="33" alt="View Ghazanfar Abbas's profile on LinkedIn">

</a>
```

removing the `border="0"` attribute, which renders as:

[image: View Ghazanfar Abbas's profile on LinkedIn]

Comment: Great. I didn't know we could use nested alternate text feature.

Comment: Nice, you've found a way to link images [without the dotted border](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xGwUL.png)! Just add some additional newlines within the `<a>` -- I never noticed that.